# Rails + Sneakers: could not obtain a connection from the pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rabbitmq, sneakers

We're using Sneakers gem in production for a big application. And sometimes the load can be so huge that one specific queue may contain over 250_000 messages. And in such cases, the exception

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: 
could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

occurs regularly.

For the database, we are using Amazon RDS based on PostgreSQL 9.6. `max_connections` PostgreSQL config value is 3296.

Our `database.yml` file:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 40
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

I guess we can increase a `pool` value, but I can't find info about how to calculate max possible value so it will not break anything.

Also, a copy of an application for background processing using Sneakers gem lives separately (but uses the same database) and can be configured individually. But right now it has the same `database.yml` config. Sneakers gem config file:

```
production:
  heartbeat: 2000
  timeout_job_after: 35
  exchange_type: :fanout
  threads: 4
  prefetch: 4
  durable: true
  ack: true
  daemonize: true
  retry_max_times: 5
  retry_timeout: 2000
  workers: 4
```

We have no problems with connections pool in base runtime application, but `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` occurs in workers very often and it is a really big problem.

So, please help me to reconfigure `databese.yml` file:

1. How to correctly calculate the max possible value for `pool` option
   if the database `max_connections` value is 3296?
2. How to correctly calculate the max possible value for `pool` option 
   when using the Sneakers gem with the configs above?
3. Or, if my configs are good, how can I avoid `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError` in workers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide the version of Rails you are using. If you are on Rails 5+ can you try wrapping your application code in `Rails.application.executor { }` (middleware or just hardcoded in your jobs) . I have no experience with Sneakers but I have a suspicion it does not release connections to the pool by itself and that should fix it. More details about the mechanism: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html . Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: @SvetlinSimonyan I'm executing worker's code inside `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection` block. If I'm not mistaken, `Rails.application.executor.wrap` uses it under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for an answer, I kept looking for a solution.

And, I guess, my very base problem was in connection pool size.

On the Sneakers gem issues tracker, I found a [comment](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/103#issuecomment-134529425) with the formula for calculating the required number of connections at full load. I changed the code from the comment a bit, so now it makes calculations taking into account the individual settings of each worker:

```
before_fork = -> {
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!
    Sneakers.logger.info('Disconnected from ActiveRecord!')
  end
}

after_fork = -> {
  def count_pool_size
    workers              = ::Sneakers::Worker::Classes
    default_threads_size = ::Sneakers.const_get(:CONFIG)[:threads]
    base_pool_size       = 3 + workers.size * 3

    if Sneakers.const_get(:CONFIG)[:share_threads]
      base_pool_size + default_threads_size
    else
      base_pool_size + connections_per_worker(workers, default_threads_size)
    end
  end

  def connections_per_worker(classes, default)
    classes.inject(0) do |sum, worker_class|
      sum + (worker_class.queue_opts[:threads] || default)
    end
  end

  def reconfig?
    Rails.env.production?
  end

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config.merge!('pool' => count_pool_size) if reconfig?

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    Sneakers.logger.info("Connected to ActiveRecord! Config: #{config}")
  end
}
```

Summary: for all workers, I need to have a limit of almost 600 connections at maximum load. But I only had 40. For now, I will use the above code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/42#issuecomment-72244263).

> Active Record didn't seem to be releasing connections after the `work()`
>   method had completed. If you pass the block using Active Record to
>   `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`, it will release the
>   connections perfectly.

```
def work(msg)
  id = JSON.parse(msg)['id']
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    user = User.find(id)
    user.name="Homer Simpson"
    user.save
  end
  ack!
end
```

Comment: I already use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229693/rails-sneakers-could-not-obtain-a-connection-from-the-pool/56950078#comment97290170_55229693